# Symmetry and transitivity with the existential quantifier

Tags: equivalence-relations, quantifiers

I can't find any resource that would indicate whether symmetry and transitivity relations are possible or not with the existential quantifier or when quantifiers are combined.

I'm interested in the following types of relations: some-to-some, all-to-some-and some-to-none. If I'm not wrong the first two kinds are examples of surjective and the last one of non-surjective function.

Intuitively, it seems to me that only in the first case both symmetry and transitivity are possible. To be honest, I don't even know how to represent transitivity with the some-to-none relations.

*Some to some:*

Symmetry: $\exists$x$\exists$y(Rxy$\Rightarrow$Ryx)

Transitivity: $\exists$x$\exists$y$\exists$z(Rxy$\land$Ryx)$\Rightarrow$Rxz

*All to some:*

Symmetry: $\forall$x$\exists$y(Rxy$\Rightarrow$$\lnot$Ryx)

Transitivity: $\forall$x$\exists$y$\exists$z(Rxy$\land$$\lnot$Ryx)$\Rightarrow$$\lnot$Rxz

*Some to none*

Relation: $\exists$x(Sx$\land$$\forall$y(Sy$\Rightarrow$$\lnot$Ryx)

Symmetry: $\exists$x(Sx$\land$$\exists$y($\lnot$Sy)$\Rightarrow$(Rxy$\Rightarrow$$\lnot$Ryx)

Transitivity: ?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking here. You first definition of symmetry is not correct.

Comment: What Tobias said. The correct definition is $(\forall x)(\forall y)(xRy \to yRx)$.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. That answers my question - i.e. symmetry is defined ONLY through universal quantifier. I suppose the same is also true for transitivity.

Comment: What is the general relation between symmetry and surjectivity? Thanks.

Comment: The general relation between symmetry and surjectivity is: none. Symmetry applies to relations, and tells you that $R^{-1} = R$. Thus the domain and range of $R$ are the same set. Surjectivity applies to functions, a special case of relations. If $R$ is in fact a function $f\colon X\to Y$ then it's surjective iff $\forall y \exists x R(x,y)$, where $R(x,y) \equiv f(x) = y$.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation @BrianO. I've mixed up several things here, I guess. Yes, R was a function. Can a surjective function also be all-to-all as in $\forall$x$\forall$y R(x,y)

Comment: A function can be all to all iff the domain and range are both empty or the range has just one element. Otherwise, if there are multiple elements of the range, say $y_1\ne y_2$, then for any $x\in X$, both $R(x,y_1)$ and $R(x,y_2)$ hold, so $R$ isn't a function (it's not single-valued).